# AppleWatch 3 Series shows 4 lines of stripes across the display

Tags: apple-watch

My AppleWatch 3 Series (GPS model) is showing 4 lines of stripes across the screen when it is off and under a direct light.

Should I go to AppleStore to check it? Or that is normal?

Comment: Do the stripes look like [this](https://www.macrumors.com/2017/10/31/apple-watch-series-3-display-edge-stripes/)?

Comment: @fsb Yes it does but across the screen, not on the sides. I counted 4 lines of striped lines

Comment: I don't have an actual 'answer' for you but I would recommend taking it to Apple.  I have a Series 2 and haven't noticed any stripes across my screen so I'm guessing there's something wrong with your display.  It should be covered by warranty.

Comment: @fsb would you please paste your comment as an answer? I was today at AppleStore and my watch is indeed defected as the article shows.

Comment: I'm happy you were able to figure out the problem and get the Watch fixed.  I have a Series 2 and I love it!

Comment: @fsb they will give me a replacement within two weeks. Hopefully not a refurbished one!! :)

Comment: @fsb currently I’m rocking my trusted Tissot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [this article](https://www.macrumors.com/2017/10/31/apple-watch-series-3-display-edge-stripes/) on MacRumors, there's been some defective Series 3 displays.  Apple is replacing them under warranty.

If it looks similar to this image, you should have no problem getting Apple to fix it.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you see this under bright bulb light under the Apple Watch screen then I think its normal. I have had this on two replacements, as show in drawing.
The drawing shows four lines from top of screen down and its also present on the edge of the watch screen. The lines are vertical but have horizontal ticks running down these lines. Hope that helps people. Hope its not a fault.

[image: Apple Watch Series 3 Lines Drawing]

Comment: I also have the same in the replacement display. I don’t understand it. Maybe those are sensors, I don’t know